# Linux device file is missing

Tags: linux, driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I find the driver specific stuff in `/sys/class/graphic/XM_403`
But in `/dev/` is no XM_403 file.

Here is the pertinent code.

```
    graphic_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,"graphic");
    device_create(graphic_class,NULL,MKDEV(MAJOR_NR,minor),NULL,"XM_403");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`device_create`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-device-create.html) creates a file within the sysfs, exactly what you are seeing.

Usually it's [`udev`](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.udev.html) that creates the device file.

Comment: I know. I thought with that command sequence creates udev the device file. So I'm wrong!? How can I encourage udev to do that?

Comment: @Peter: is `udev` running? Take a look at `udevadm monitor` when you load the driver.

Comment: @ Internet... your clue was right `udevadm` -> `unknown command`